# ionic ng-model do not works correct

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on ionic project. I don't know why, but `ng-model` do not work correct.I have started new project with default `starter` called [tabs](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs)

When I open the browser I see "my custom text" in the input field, but when I change it, in the console I see same text "my custom text", but it should be changed with my input. So changes do not applied on the `$scope.getUserName`. I tried to debug and found that it creates own `$scope` inside the `$scope` of the `DashCtrl`, But when i tried to get access to it like this `$scope.child` I got `undefined`.

Can anyone explain me what's going on and what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code from `www/js/controllers.js`

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.getUserName = 'my custom text';

    $scope.nameChange = function(){
       console.log($scope.getUserName); 
    };

})

.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});

  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  };
})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
  $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
})

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };
});
```

And this is my `www/templates/tab-dash.html`

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <h2>Welcome to Ionic</h2>
     <input ng-model="getUserName" ng-change="nameChange()"  name="anim" class="my-input"
         aria-describedby="inputDescription" />
    <p>
    This is the Ionic starter for tabs-based apps. For other starters and ready-made templates, check out the <a href="http://market.ionic.io/starters" target="_blank">Ionic Market</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
      To edit the content of each tab, edit the corresponding template file in <code>www/templates/</code>. This template is <code>www/templates/tab-dash.html</code>
    </p>
    <p>
    If you need help with your app, join the Ionic Community on the <a href="http://forum.ionicframework.com" target="_blank">Ionic Forum</a>. Make sure to <a href="http://twitter.com/ionicframework" target="_blank">follow us</a> on Twitter to get important updates and announcements for Ionic developers.
    </p>
    <p>
      For help sending push notifications, join the <a href="https://apps.ionic.io/signup" target="_blank">Ionic Platform</a> and check out <a href="http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-overview" target="_blank">Ionic Push</a>. We also have other services available.
    </p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I just figured out where is the problem.

I replaced `ng-model="getUserName"` with ng-model="userObject.username" and same in the`/controllers.js`

So now it looks like this

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.userObject = {
        username: 'custom'
    }

    $scope.nameChange = function(){
       console.log($scope.userObject.username); 
    };

})
```

To understand why now everything works check out this article.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes